# Create Entry Data Form (multiple rows) in Google Sheet with Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script, data-entry

i am new beginner in App Script.
I want to create entry data form (sheet Form Entry) to Database sheet with multiple rows and columns of data.

Please share you advise.

I share googlesheet link below:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12FSa4Ns7_CRsQDsWF_Xx8WHMAg1xl35ocgV6E7CoSdQ/edit?usp=sharing

I have learned about this from Youtube but they only showed with simple one row data.
I also tried with macro recording and also failed.

Comment: You can use an array literal assignment to collect many individual cells of data all at one time with one `getValues()` as opposed to many `getValue()`s .  Some volunteers are willing to share their emails to access your spreadsheet.  I am not.

Comment: Thank you for including a spreadsheet in your question. However the question must stand on its own, and you cannot/should not expect that users can/should/will open your spreadsheet to understand your question. Would you please edit the body of your question to include information about your scenario, purpose and details of your form, and the database you are creating.